# Facebook APP is blocked from sending messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, private-messaging, sap-crm

We use SAP CRM Interaction Center to answer Facebook posts/messages to our company page. We created a Facebook APP to manage our pages using Facebook API and Page_Access_Token.

Scenario:

1. Facebook User sends private message to one of our company pages.
2. Message is delegated to the Interaction Center Inbox.
3. Interaction Center Agent replies with a private Message.
4. Private message is received by Facebook User.

It working fine when Facebook User uses messenger on his/her mobile phone or uses Desktop PC/Laptop and is logged in the whole time. When he/she logs off and logs in again (Desktop PC/Laptop) the private message sent by Interaction Center/Facebook APP is replaced by following text:

> "This message was removed because the APP it's being sent from is
> blocked from sending messages"

We also tried to use Graph API Explorer for testing and it does not work:

Following [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/conversation/messages) we used:

```
post-> /v2.4/thread_id/messages?message="Test"
```

Is also working if the private message was sent to my account. I created the APP and I am administration of our page.

Facebook APP: All permissions are selected (maybe we do not need all); Status is in Development; It is not a test APP;

Based on the cases where private messaging is working I assume that everything is correct on SAP CRM side. But we clearly missed something when we created the APP.

Any ideas how to solve this?
Do we have to submit the APP for review? (It should not be public)
Is it possible that Facebook considers the messages as spam and blocked the APP automatically?

Thanks,
SImon

Comment: That sounds strange. Facebook might block apps from using certain features, if user feedback is negative – but then it should not work at all any more, and you should get an error every time you try to reply to a message. I’d say, file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: The issue is solved. This is my first APP and I was not smart enough:-) I changed the APP from development mode to public. Now everything is fine. Thanks a lot for your effort and sorry for the trouble.